# get cod 500 internal server error when try to display in ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, web, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to generate server report as pdf from web api. I used Microsoft ReportViewer 11.0. And I get errors below. The report page show blank and nothing error show in VS. But In Fiddler, Its respond internal server(500 code).
[it completely write to local pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCuGx.png)

[I get error like this when try to display report. Plz help me guys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsBJ5.png)
and here is my code

```
re.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(pReportURL);
        re.ServerReport.ReportPath = ReportPath;

        re.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        IReportServerCredentials irc = new ReportServerCredentials(pReportUserName, ReportPAssword, pReportURL);
        re.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irc;
        Int32 i = 0;
        ReportParameter[] rptParm = new ReportParameter[hdParam.Count];
        if (rptParm != null)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry index in hdParam)
            {
                if (i <= hdParam.Count)
                {
                    rptParm[i] = new ReportParameter(index.Key.ToString(), index.Value.ToString());
                    i = i + 1;
                }





            }
            re.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptParm);
        }
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension; 
        re.ServerReport.DisplayName = ReportPath;
        byte[] data = re.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(data);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        Stream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        //ms.WriteTo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\testpdf.pdf", data);
        var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("PrintOut_Finance_Inv/pdf");
        return result;
```

Comment: Did you try to use a `try catch` block to see the exception?

Comment: oh I forget to try it i will try it now to catch exception. ty sir